# React call function from another function in a loop

Tags: reactjs

I am writing a React class and trying to call a function form another function but in a for loop, I am getting this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: isValidated is not defined

If I move my function call out of for each loop, it work fine. I am using arrow function, so I believe I don;t need binding in constructor.

```js
class ResourceManagerForm extends React.Component {
        render() {
        return (<button className="ms-Button ms-Button--primary" onClick={this.onSaveButtonClick}>
                    <span className="ms-Button-label">Create Account name</span> 
                </button>)
    }
    isValidated = (control) =>
    {
        //some code here
    }
    onSaveButtonClick = (e) =>
    {
        this.isValidated(null);  //works fine here
        $("#resource-manager [id]").each(function (index, value)
        {
                if(isValidated(value)) //does not work
                {

                }
                if(this.isValidated(value)) //also does not work
                {

                }
        }); 
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of how you define the anonymous function in `.each()`

For `this` to be bound inside the function, you need to declare it as an "arrow" function i.e. `(index, value) => { ... }` instead of `function(index, value) { ... }`:

```
this.isValidated(null);  //works fine here
$("#resource-manager [id]").each((index, value) => {
    if(this.isValidated(value)) { // this is bound inside the function now

    }
});
```

This [blog post](https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/when-to-use-arrow-functions/) explains how arrow functions behave.